# Where can I find Consumer Technology?

Tags: elite-dangerous

I don't know where to find Consumer Technology. I looked on the wikis, but couldn't find any info.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consumer technology is produced by High Tech systems. You can find a high tech system near you by going to your galaxy map. In the "View" tab, you can filter systems by economy type. Deselect all but High Tech and you may have a system to work with.

[image: Illustration of the appropriate options to select to find high-tech systems]

Alternatively, there are third-party tools available to help you find a particular commodity near you. [eddb](http://eddb.io/) has such an option, for example. Go to the "Commodities" page, select what you want, enter your current location and indicate that you want to buy that commodity and then it'll give you a list of all stations that stock that commodity, as well as its last reported price.